# Curl link with django tastypie with ApiKey authorization and Django REST Framework

Tags: django, parsing, curl, django-rest-framework, tastypie

My goal si to read data via API that I have created with django tastypie.
It is working great with and without authentication. I tested it with Postman.

Problem that I am having is how to do CURL with authentication. If I do without authentication

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spaceship/?format=json
```

I have 200 Successful response and I can see the JSON feed.

But if I do with authentication

resources.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from main.models import Spaceship
from tastypie.authentication import ApiKeyAuthentication
from django.db.models import signals
from tastypie.models import create_api_key

signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

class SpaceshipResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Spaceship.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'spaceship'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

In postman if I add Authentication ApiKey user:343jh43k2j4h3k24h, it works. "343jh43k2j4h3k24h" is ApiKey created in Django Admin.

What would be the proper CURL sentence to pass user with ApiKey that I got 200 Response and I can see the JSON data and parse it later?

Something like this I am not sure how to write it properly:

```
curl -H "Authorization: user 343jh43k2j4h3k24h" 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spaceship/?format=json'
```

My goal is to do this:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spaceship/?format=json')
```

I need that URL to be with ApiKey Authentication, not sure how to do it. What is the proper way, the most efficient way.

Comment: You can over ride the get_authorization_data() function inside the AuthenticationClass which extracts the data from the header 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'. You can write your own logic of extracting it from the request object through query params. Check the source: https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py